# wordpress fcm plugin not working on scheduled posts correctly

Tags: plugins

I am very new to wordpress/php, I don't fully understand it yet.

So I've implemented firebase cloud messaging in a wordpress app and I am able to send push notifications with "FCM Push Notification from WP" plugin, and it also works with scheduled posts IF the admin panel is open when the scheduled post is due. Otherwise it will send the notification when I browse to the admin panel. I really don't understand this code fully, but what could I do to make sure it runs even though I am not logged in as admin?

[image: This is the hooks defined in the plugin]

[image: This is the method the functions in the add_action() runs]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I don't know the events here myself, but I can't see how all of this is wired up: you've posted add_actions and then a different function?

Comment: Also it's generally easier to read copy / pasted code rather than screenshots. Use ```php to mark the start of a code block, and another three backticks to end it.

Comment: I wonder if you've set something up as a scheduled task though, and you're just not getting enough cron events to fire when you expect it to.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

```php add_action('future_to_publish', array($this, 'fcmdpplgpn_future_to_publish'), 10, 1); ```

Calls ```php function fcmdpplgpn_future_to_publish($post)
    {
        //$this->write_log('fcmdpplgpn_future_to_publish: CHAMOU EVENTO');
        $this->fcmdpplgpn_send_notification_on_save($post, true);
    } ```

And the send_notification_on_save is shown in the printscreen above. 

The fcmdpplgn_notification method is extremely long, too long to copy paste here but it builds up the notification object and then sends it with curl.

Comment: @Rup When I publish a post from admin panel there is an option  in the publish section where I can schedule a post, that's what I am doing.

Comment: Nothing can happen on your WordPress site unless WordPress runs, and this only happens when somebody loads it. If your front end is cached then this will only be when the admin is loaded. So future posts are published the first time somebody visits the site after the publication date. If your site is in development and you’re the only one visiting it’s not going to be published until you visit. You can use cron to periodically trigger a visit automatically every x minutes. Just search Google for “WordPress cron” and you find more info.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I was under the impression that it ran as long as the server was up and running. 

I will look into it right away! Appreciate your response!